# Firebase - Is it possible to execute cloud function when a particular document is read?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a realtime database on Firebase. In it, I have a document named `/queue` with many children. I want to execute a cloud function, whenever this `/queue` is fetched. Is this possible? I already have cloud functions setup for onCreate, onUpdate, onDelete events. Just want to setup a cloud function for on fetch/get event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as you have noticed, this will not be possible with the "standard" Realtime Database triggers, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#set_the_event_handler.

However, you could "go through" (i.e .use) a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to fetch the desired Realtime Database node and obtain a similar result.

The sequence would be as follows:

1. The Callable Cloud Function is triggered from the front-end, passing the Realtime Database node path to be fetched (e.g. `/queue`);
2. The Cloud Function runs. Therefore you know that there was a fetch and you can execute any business logic (e.g. [update a counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)). After executing this logic, you fetch the doc (through the Admin SDK) and send back the result of the fetch to the front-end.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking that this would be the final approach.